# Async function in Node js doesn't call the function that is suppose to be Called After its execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am working on a project where I need to use electron js (I am new to javascript). When I tried to use the `electron.remote.dialog.showOpenDialog` function, it does not call the function that is supposed to execute after async functions execution (`console.log`). The Sync method was successful and the Async is not. If someone can help  please help me.
Here is the code.

**Async method (unsuccessful)**

```
const { dialog } = require("electron").remote;

dirButton = document.getElementById('select-file')

function getDir(e) {
  dialog.showOpenDialog(
    { properties: ["openDirectory", "openFile"] },
    console.log
  );
}
dirButton.addEventListener("click",  getDir);
```

**Sync method (successful)**

```
const { dialog } = require("electron").remote;

dirButton = document.getElementById('select-file')

function getDir(e) {
  dirr = dialog.showOpenDialogSync(
    { properties: ["openDirectory", "openFile"] },
  );
  console.log(dirr)
}
dirButton.addEventListener("click",  getDir);
```

Comment: [`showOpenDialog` does not accept a callback](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options)…!? Instead it returns a promise, so `dialog.showOpenDialog(...).then(console.log)`…!?

Comment: `dialog.showOpenDialog(...).then(console.log)` worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this in Async call because it returns promise.

```
function getDir(e) {
  dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ["openDirectory", "openFile"] }).
  then(result => {
      console.log(result)
   }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
   })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your Async method should be like this**

```
const { dialog } = require("electron").remote;

dirButton = document.getElementById('select-file')

const getDir = async (e) => {
    const dirr = await dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ["openDirectory", "openFile"] });
    console.log(dirr);
}

dirButton.addEventListener("click",  getDir);
```